# How can I translate "Survey" and "Surveying" into Brazilian Portuguese?

Tags: português-brasileiro, tradução

I am working on a menu for a form selector and need to figure out a few terms into Brazilian Portuguese. These are options within the form.

These are also stand alone options so no additional context or examples will be given as if I laid down examples with it's usages within sentences, it would defeat the purposes of what I am trying to get as an answer.

The terms I need help with are:

> Survey
>
> Surveying
>
> Survey Fields
>
> Survey Tools

Again, they are stand alone options within a form builder. I have considered "Campos de Inquerito", "Campos de Pesquisa", "Ferramentas de PEsquisa", but wonder if there are better options. Also when it comes to "Survey" or "Surveying" I'm not sure what to consider. Is there even a 'single' translation word that we can use it in Brazilian Portuguese?

Comment: What exactly does a "survey field" mean in this context?

Comment: Also, your suggested translations are confusing me. The use of the term "surveying" in the English makes it sound like you're talking about *topografia/topologia*, but your translations make it sound like you're talking about *pesquisas de campo*. Please edit your question to explain what the form builder is for.

Comment: I would argue that if the context relates to search, "pesquisa" would be the most adequate translation. On the other hand, if the context is data collection, "inquérito" would probably fit the bill better

Comment: I know what it is, I dreaded those surveys when I live in Canada, and now I'm plagued by them again in Brazil. I'm almost sure there are precedents on those translations already.

Comment: Sorry guys.. I didn't come around to answering all your questions and requests for additional input but Ramon nailed it.  Best!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forms are a common application in Brazil and there are a few translations that have become well-known by the general public. The preferred translation for `survey` seems to be `questionário`, as evidenced by my overflowing inbox:

[image]

Most online survey applications also prefer the term `questionário`:

[image]

<sup>source: [Survey Monkey em Português](https://pt.surveymonkey.com/home/)</sup>

[image]

<sup>source: [Survey Monkey](https://www.surveymonkey.com/home/)</sup>

Following that rationale, `Survey Fields` and `Survey Tools` would translate to `Campos de Questionário` and `Ferramentas de Questionário`, respectively. The downside of this is that `Surveying` doesn't have a direct translation, but you can express actions with an auxiliary verb: `Aplicando Questionários`.

As you could see in my inbox picture, `Pesquisa` is also a popular term, and it is just as good. If you go with it, then `Survey Fields`, `Survey Tools` and `Surveying` will translate to `Campos de Pesquisa`, `Ferramentas de Pesquisa` and `Pesquisando`, respectively.

`Pesquisa` was Google's choice for localizing its Forms web application:

[image]

<sup>source: [Formulários Google](https://www.google.com/intl/pt-BR/forms/about/)</sup>

[image]

<sup>source: [Google Forms](https://www.google.com/intl/en-US/forms/about/)</sup>

Comment: Thank Ramon! That totally settled it! Gotta go adjust some strings now! hehe  :D

Comment: @Hugo I'm glad my daily spam managed to help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Survey is basically **pesquisa** like SurveyMonkey is a website for **Pesquisas** (Survey)

Answer (score -1):

Based on [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/survey) Survey is:

- Noun:  an examination of opinions, behaviour, etc.
- Verb: to look at or examine all of something, especially carefully

```
                        NOUN                    VERB

    Survey              Exame                   Examinar

    Surveying                                   Examinando

    Survey Fields       Área de Exame

    Survey Tools        Ferramentas de Exame
```

Comment: If you're using that meaning of "survey", why is this better than the word "pesquisa" that Hugo suggested? I've know I've heard "pesquisa de campo" used in this context, but never "exame" before.

Comment: A palavra "pesquisa" parece se encaixar mais no contexto do que "exame"

Comment: Acho que o site [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/enpt/Survey) pode ajudar nessas traduções.